# Saving object while the object could be changed

Tags: c#, .net

I want to serialize an object and after that it shall be saved to the disk. The serialization takes a lot of time. So instead of serializing it synchronously, I want to save the "freezed" data at this point. But because of the size of the object, it should not be deep copied.
Is there any technique to do it?

Graph to show the procedure:
[image]

Comment: What type of serialization (binary, xml, json)?

Comment: Xml serialization

Comment: Use Xml Linq which is much faster than Xml serialization.  Xml serialization needs a complete xml with closing tag to work,

Comment: Unfortunately taht isn't a option. I want to exclude the saving logic to a parallel task

Comment: You cannot use serializer!!!  What do you mean by "saving logic to a parallel task"

Comment: I want to save the data of myobject. Therefore I use a xml serialization. The result of the serialization is saved to a file. While the serialization and saving to a file, it should not impact the sync part of the program. It should only saved the data to the time when there was the call for saving.